# Restrict search to the last week of appointments

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to grab the last week of appointments using VBA in Outlook.

I'm using the .Restrict method, but something is making my string grab 3 years further back.

I start by declaring formatted dates for my time bracket:

```
myStart = Format(DateAdd("d", -7, Now()), "ddddd h:nn AMPM")
myEnd = Format(Now(), "ddddd h:nn AMPM")
```

I build a string to hold my restriction criterion.

```
strRestriction = "[Start] <= '" & myEnd _
& "' AND [End] >= '" & myStart & "'"
```

Finally I call restrict on my appointment items:

```
Set oRestrItems = oItems.Restrict(strRestriction)
```

For a little more context, here's how I use/call the result:

```
For Each oApptItem In oRestrItems 'oItems will grab everything, but that's hardly perfect.
    If oApptItem.Sensitivity <> olPrivate Then
        MsgBox (oApptItem.Subject)
        MsgBox (oApptItem.Start)
        MsgBox (oApptItem.End)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: If you make it easier for responders to help you, there is a better chance of getting a response. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

I can guess that you are missing two statements.

```
oItems.IncludeRecurrences = True
oItems.Sort "[Start]"
```

If this is the case, you can ask another question about why the Restrict requires these additional statements. Someone may have an answer.

Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Try commenting out either or both statements. You should see that the items are not the same.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LastWeekAppts()

Dim objFolder As Folder

Dim oItems As items
Dim oRestrItems As items

Dim strRestriction As String
Dim myStart As Date
Dim myEnd As Date

Dim temp As Object

Set objFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
Set oItems = objFolder.items

' *****************************************
' Odd results without these two statements
oItems.IncludeRecurrences = True
oItems.Sort "[Start]"
' *****************************************

myEnd = Date
myStart = DateAdd("d", -7, Date)

Debug.Print " myStart: " & myStart
Debug.Print " myEnd  : " & myEnd

strRestriction = "[Start] <= '" & myEnd _
                      & "' AND [End] >= '" & myStart & "'"
Debug.Print strRestriction

Set oRestrItems = oItems.Restrict(strRestriction)

For Each temp In oRestrItems
    Debug.Print temp.start & " - " & temp.Subject
Next temp

End Sub
```